# Is Hillary Clinton a super delegate in 2020?

Tags: united-states, hillary-clinton, democratic-primary

Does Hillary Clinton get super-delegate status 2020? I know the list is generally viewed as "party insiders" but when is it named? Will she be the kind of insider that gets to vote after the pledged delegates?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**No, she is not.**

In order to qualify as a superdelegate, you must be (in addition to being a Democrat) at least one of:

- A member of either house of the US Congress (including non-voting delegates) [Rule 9.A.3]
- A state governor, territorial governor, or Mayor of Washington DC
- An elected member of the Democratic National Committee [Rule 9.A.1]
- A "distinguished party leader", meaning current or former Presidents, Vice Presidents, Congressional Leaders, and DNC Chairs [Rules 9.A.2 and 9.A.5]

Hillary Clinton is none of these, and so she does not qualify as a superdelegate.

Source: [Democratic Party](https://democrats.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2020-Delegate-Selection-Rules-12.17.18-FINAL.pdf)

Comment: However, stating the obvious, *Bill* Clinton does qualify, and she might have some influence on him in that respect.

Comment: For clarity, are all of the bullet points required to be a superdelegate, or would one of the four suffice?

Comment: @user45266 - Just one of the four.  I don't think it's possible to meet the first and second points simultaneously.

Comment: I'm surprised former secretaries aren't considered distinguished party leaders. Sec State, Sec Def, AG etc are some of the most powerful positions in the government

Comment: I'm surprised she's not on the DNC. Perez for example was merely Obama's Labor Secretary. I guess it's the fact that the DNC has hierarchical structure, so it's hard to have more then one semi-well-known person on it. The [rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_National_Committee#Current_leadership) are probably people most here haven't even heard of.

Comment: What does "either house of the US Congress" mean?  Does this rather mean the house of representatives vs. the senate?  (i.e. the two chambers of congress?)

Comment: @KirkWoll 9.A.3 says "All Democratic members of the United
States House of Representatives and all
Democratic members of the United
States Senate; ..." so, either chamber of Congress.

Comment: @KirkWoll House and chamber are synonyms in the context.

Comment: @Fizz - the most recent re-alignment happened when she was the candidate, or as a result of the confirmation that the DNC tried to stack the deck for Clinton. Doesn't seem feasible that she'd wind up on the DNC given those circumstances. We'll see how things shake out after the next national convention.